# Unable to configure Asp.net identity 2.2 using ADO.Net

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, asp.net-identity

Is there any way to use ado.net in configuration of identity in asp.net core. We are looking not  to use EF in this process , I have research in found EF is the default  package but we are not looking to use this . 
Can you please help me to solve this issue .

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Custom Storage Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

The link provided is the documentation on how to use different data stores and data access mechanisms than those provided by default.

You might also need to view [Customize Identity Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

But I would say the first link is where you need to start.

The first link provides starting point. You will need to create your own classes for User, Role etc....

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for your reply ,Is there a way to remove ,"services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();""   EntityFramework and sql server ado.net ? please help

Comment: Yes.  I do not use Entity Framework at all.. You need custom Storage Provider and also to create your own User and Role classes.

Comment: So by implementing the custom storage provider using ado.net, this will allow to use UserManager for example the same way we did with EF? Thank you.

Comment: @eaglei22 yes you will be able to use the same artifacts just that the hydration of said artifacts will be different. in other words it won't use EF.  I have not used EF in more than 10 years. Even with the latest version NET 8 I do not use EF

Comment: Thanks for the follow up @JonathanAlfaro! Same here, would prefer not to be forced to use EF, having worked with it on past projects.. Too many times I get side stepped and delayed because I can't easily figure out/find a solution to customize something handed off and controlled by EF (for the Identity Framework anyway).